# Static table cells with detail

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, master-detail

I'm trying to make an iOS '`information`' or '`guide`' app in Swift. I wanted to utilise the Master Detail template so that when the user clicks a cell it will take them to a relevant `ViewController` with either basic text labels or a PDF file.

From what I understand, Dynamic Cells can be dynamically changed whilst the app runs however I want to set static cells from the storyboard (or programmatically) and their relevant content/PDF files so the user can view each one. I don't want any "`new cell`" or "`editing`" functionality.

How can I make this work? I would post my code so far but it's almost identical to the Master Detail template so I don't see any use. I know this is quite a vague question but I need help and don't know where to start.

Any help will be so appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A static table cell can entirely be created via storyboard. In the storyboard once you add a tableviewcpntroller you can prototype call added to it.You can add as many prototype cells to your table ( not necessarily every one should have common layout). After all cells are added you can assign individual tags to the cells if you need identify these cells from your code.You can add segue from each cells to move to different page.
Let me know if something more is needed.

Comment: If I have seperate view controllers for every single cell, won't my app be really large in size?

Answer (score 0):

- In Interface Builder set the `Content` of the table view to `Static Cells`.
- Drag as many table view cells as you need into the table view.
- In the controller create IBOutlets for the labels and the other UI elements.
- Connect the outlets in Interface Builder.
- Rather than using the `datasource` methods assign the values directly to the UI elements via the outlets.